# Ao apagar um caractere, como fazer para executar algo?

Tags: java, android

Estou utilizando este método para apagar o último caractere digitado numa `TextView`:

```
texto = txtTexto.getText().toString();
int length = texto.length();  
txtTexto.setText(texto.substring(0, length - 1));
```

Porém ao apagar um caractere, tipo um ponto `"."`, eu quero que execute algo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Não está muito claro o que você deseja fazer, mas se for checar se o último caractere é um ponto, faça:

```
int length = texto.length();

if (texto.substring(length - 1, length).equals(".")) {
    funcao_qualquer();
}

texto = txtTexto.getText().toString();
txtTexto.setText(texto.substring(0, length - 1));
```

Comment: "Porém ao apagar um caractere, tipo um ponto ".", eu quero que execute algo." Ele deseja chamar uma função ao apagar o último caractere da `textview`.